# Regexp within a regexp OR pattern within a match OR find commas between two strings

Tags: regex

I want to extract commas `,` from this string:

`"(""2018-10-15 00:00:00.571913"",147,55,2,341.920,-4.829,-1,""0,0,427799008,307238900,163872717,122358998,115140912,112840222,111386391,109396581,107696294,107176835,106021975,104275830,`

But I don't want to extract ALL commas `,`

Only the one situated between `"",` and `,""`

Using https://regexr.com/ I have tried:

`(?="",)(\,)(?=,"")`

instead of

`(?="",)(.*)(?=,"")`

But it won't work.

This match output should be:
`, , , , ,`

In other words, in the sub-string `"",147,55,2,341.920,-4.829,-1,""` I only want to extract the commas and nothing else.

PS: In need to do it in one step.

Comment: There is no `, , , , ,` in your target string, how does it match that ?

Comment: If your engine supports the `\G` and `\K` constructs, it is doable.

Comment: Otherwise it has to be done in 2 steps `(?s)(?<="",)((?:(?!,"").)*?,(?!,"").)*)(?=,"")` Then strip the non-comma contents of capture group 1.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @Toto: it's for Matlab in the end

Comment: @sln. Thank you but if I copy paste your solution in https://regexr.com/ it does not highlight the wanted commas.

Comment: @pierebean - I too had that problem [\(?s\)\(?<="",\)\(\(?:\(?!,""\).\)*?,\(?:\(?!,""\).\)*\)\(?=,""\)](https://regex101.com/r/rUvnZN/1) but now I don't.

Comment: @sln Have you tried your pattern on regexr.com ? It does not highlight only the wanted commas.

Comment: @pierebean  - `highlight only the wanted commas` and what's your suggestion ? I mean, I know what I would do ..

Answer (score 0):

I would take a two-step approach to this.

1. Find what's between `"",`and `,""` . You were close, but unless it's different in Matlab you have 2 positive lookaheads in your description `(?=)` rather than a positive lookbehind  `(?<=)` and a positive lookahead. I'd use this in Java:

   `(?<=["]{2},)[0-9,.\\-]+(?=,["]{2})`

So a positive lookbehind preceding the pattern, then the pattern (one or more commas, periods, hyphens and/or numbers), and then a positive lookahead after the pattern. This yields: `147,55,2,341.920,-4.829,-1`

2. Then in this String just match comma `,` and collect them all.

Comment: Thank you for input. I have already implemeted this two step appraoch. But I need to do it in one step. This is the difficulty I have.

Comment: Also, if I copy paste your pattern in regexr.com it does not highlight anything.

Comment: For me it highlights `147,55,2,341.920,-4.829,-1` . It does give a warning that the positive lookbehind may not be supported in all browsers. I'm using Google Chrome and Regex Engine set to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for MATLAB, you can't get a single match that contains non-contiguous characters in one step. However, instead of using regexp, you could try regexprep to erase the parts you don't care about:

```
function testFunc()

    str = '"(""2018-10-15 00:00:00.571913"",147,55,2,341.920,-4.829,-1,""0,0,427799008,307238900,163872717,122358998,115140912,112840222,111386391,109396581,107696294,107176835,106021975,104275830,';

    middlePattern = '(?<=,).*?(?=,)';
    beginningPattern = '^[^,]*,';
    endPattern = ',".*?$';

    exp = [middlePattern '|' beginningPattern '|' endPattern];

    str = regexprep(str,exp,'')

>> testFunc

  str =

    ',,,,,'
```

My solution doesn't contain the spaces that your desired solution has. I couldn't get that to work.

Could you expand on why you want a list of commas and what your ultimate goal is?